# Have a Web Application Design in mind but I don't know where to start

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, heroku, playframework

I am very new to webApp design and have entered this competition in school which requires me to submit a fully functional application in next 2 days. So here is my design that I am planning on implementing.  Assume there is

```
A <-----> Application <-----> B
```

A can converse with B only through the application. A has its own database in which it stores some details and B has its own database in which it stores its personal info. However some of the fields of data in A and B might be same. So I would require to deploy this application to do the talking between A and B. I would require that the Application help perform update operation on A's database by querying B and matching corresponding fields. In general fetch data from B for A and help update A's database.

Constraints: This application  needs to be developed using Java Play platform and has to  be deployed on heroku. Could you please help me to start off? I have seen and deployed the sample app from Java Play website. I am new to Json/javascript and Ajax (kind if what I should be using). So can someone point me to a sample code which does it or some tutorial which is learner friendly? May be some help on where to start etc? Any help would be very very much appreciated.  And btw it is not a homework and we are allowed to use ANY resource we want to.

Comment: It's usually best to start off with something and hit a wall. *That's* when you ask us.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I am confused about the first thing here. What should A and B be. I know I want an application running in the middle. But should A and B have their DB also on the cloud? Should they be like sending say some Json queries to the application? This is my first ever time developing an application. So kinda lost

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I guess I ll try writing some basic application which can just accept some sort of request. May be then add functionality to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are confused about what A and B are *in the context of your problem*. They are not *Applications* (and neither your description, nor the diagram implies they are). They are two data stores. So you don't have 3 applications and two databases; you have *one application* (what you have to write), which could connect to two databases.

Of course, outside the boundaries of your problem there may exist two applications which create records in A and B databases; but for your problem you can ignore them.